# Multivariable calculus saddle point- does these 2 conditions are equivalent?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

I was explained that in order to determine if a point **is a saddle point** I I should check if the determinant of the hassian matrix is negative.

Then I was looking online and found an article saying that we can just check if we have one positive Eigenvalue and one negative (and all other Eigenvalue are not zero)

If these 2 conditions are actually equivalent, I would really appreciate to get some intuition for why they are equivalent

Comment: Are you only considering functions of two variables, $f: \Bbb{R}^2 \to \Bbb{R}$? If yes, then the two statements are equivalent. In higher dimensions, it is no longer true

Comment: For the intuition, recall the determinant is the product of eigenvalues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For functions from $\Bbb R^2$ into $\Bbb R$, it is true. Asserting that the determinant of the Hessian is negative is the same thing as asserting the there are eigenvalues with different signs.

But it is false for functions from $\Bbb R^3$ into $\Bbb R$. Take $f(x,y,z)=-x^2-y^2-z^2$ at $(0,0,0)$. The determinant of the Hessian there is $-8$, but $f$ has a maximum at that point: all eigenvalues are negative.

Comment: I considered all function with n variables in general, also did you meant to write y instead the secon x?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. And the statements are equivalent for $n=2$, but not in general.

Comment: these was really helpful! thank you so much! so what is the right condition to check a saddle point?

Comment: There is at least an eigenvalue greater than $0$ and there is at least an eigenvalue smaller than $0$.